# Cannot get email category color on outlook

Tags: vb.net, blueprism

I am not able to output the color category of my email on Outlook. Basically, I tried to use the VB code provided by Microsoft Docs to output the name of the color. See image below for reference:
As input, I am giving a Entry_ID which is extracted from the email. This will be basically used in Blue Prism as a code stage
[image]

```
 Dim item = _nameSpace.GetItemFromID(Entry_ID)
 Dim objCategory As Category
 Dim strOutput As String 
 strOutput = ""
 
 ' Check if the Categories collection for the Namespace 
 ' contains one or more Category objects. 
 If item.Categories.Count > 0 Then 
 
 ' Enumerate the Categories collection, checking 
 ' the value of the Color property for 
 ' each Category object. 
 For Each objCategory In item.Categories 
 
 ' Add the name of the Category object to 
 ' the output string. 

 

 strOutput = strOutput & objCategory.Name 
 
 ' Add information about the assigned color 
 ' to the output string. 
 Select Case objCategory.Color 
 Case OlCategoryColor.olCategoryColorNone 
 strOutput = strOutput & ": No color" & vbCrLf 
 Case OlCategoryColor.olCategoryColorBlack 
 strOutput = strOutput & ": Black " & vbCrLf 
 Case OlCategoryColor.olCategoryColorBlue 
 strOutput = strOutput & ": Blue" & vbCrLf 
 Case OlCategoryColor.olCategoryColorGray 
 strOutput = strOutput & ": Gray" & vbCrLf 
 Case OlCategoryColor.olCategoryColorGreen 
 strOutput = strOutput & ": Green" & vbCrLf 
 Case OlCategoryColor.olCategoryColorMaroon 
 strOutput = strOutput & ": Maroon" & vbCrLf 
 Case OlCategoryColor.olCategoryColorOlive 
 strOutput = strOutput & ": Olive" & vbCrLf 
 Case OlCategoryColor.olCategoryColorOrange 
 strOutput = strOutput & ": Orange" & vbCrLf 
 Case OlCategoryColor.olCategoryColorPeach 
 strOutput = strOutput & ": Peach" & vbCrLf 
 Case OlCategoryColor.olCategoryColorPurple 
 strOutput = strOutput & ": Purple" & vbCrLf 
 Case OlCategoryColor.olCategoryColorRed 
 strOutput = strOutput & ": Red" & vbCrLf 
 Case OlCategoryColor.olCategoryColorSteel 
 strOutput = strOutput & ": Steel" & vbCrLf 
 Case OlCategoryColor.olCategoryColorTeal 
 strOutput = strOutput & ": Teal" & vbCrLf 
 Case OlCategoryColor.olCategoryColorYellow 
 strOutput = strOutput & ": Yellow" & vbCrLf 
 Case Else 
 strOutput = strOutput & ": Unknown" & vbCrLf 
 End Select 
 Next 
 End If 
 
categoryColor = strOutput
 ' Display the output string. 
 'MsgBox strOutput
 
 ' Clean up. 
 'Set objCategory = Nothing 
 'Set objNameSpaceitem = Nothing 
 
'End Sub

 

'categoryColor = objCategory
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help are expected to detail the expected behavior of the code along with a description of the actual behavior occurring.

Comment: Yep. What's happening? Do you get any errors?